# AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'rollback' from Google Colab when connecting Postgresql via SQL extension

Tags: sqlalchemy, google-colaboratory

The following code in Google Colab worked fine until early July 2023 and now it is generating an error:

```
%load_ext SQL
!pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.47
# Restart runtime
%sql postgresql://ID:PW@host:5432/db_name
```

The exact error message is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sql/magic.py", line 203, in execute
    conn.internal_connection.rollback()
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'rollback'
```

I found that the Python version is now 3.10.12 and it may be related. I had some similar issues last time and I solved by downgrading SQLAlchemy version.

Anyone having similar issues?